# Huawei Dongle E3372 getting Private Ip address

Tags: networking, usb-modem, huawei

I want to use Huawei E3372h dongle for some LTE experiments. As you can see from following image that WAN ip is 172.16.0.2 but in my interface in Ubuntu I'm getting 192.168.8.100.

[image: Dongle Scrrenshot]

I want that wan IP as my interface IP. How can I do that .....

Second question : I can not ping 172.16.0.2 from 172.16.0.1 but I can ping from dongle 172.16.0.1.

Please help me